# How to modify the decimal separator of the tasks package?

Tags: tasks

By default, the decimal separator of the tasks package is the period. In French, it is the comma. How to make the following code display a comma while keeping the period in the source code?

In other words, the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}[item-format=\ensuremath](1)
\task 0.6\times0.7=0.42
\task 0.05\times0.1=0.005
\task 0.07\times0.08=0.0056
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

looks like this:

[image: avec virgule]

and not as this:

[image: sans virgule]

Comment: Fun. If I add `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` (and T1 fonts, *ça va sans dire*), it works. But with `[french]`, it doesn't, maybe there some option...

Comment: Not in French with this code `\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` I updated the question code.

Comment: Yes, I know. But if you try `spanish` you'll have your comma, so there should be some trick done there (I'm looking for it). Hardly compatible with `french`, I fear...

Comment: Would locally forcing the language to Spanish be acceptable ? (I mean, in the `item-format`)

Comment: If there is no other solution, this is a decent way to do it. I will write to the package maintainer to add something that handles this.

Answer (score 2):

When using `spanish` in `babel`, the decimal point in math mode numbers is automatically changed to a comma(*). The code doing the magic is in [`spanish.ldf` around line 664](https://github.com/jbezos/babel-spanish/blob/af260b95515c2b81c0550bcef923dc3de18a078d/spanish.dtx#L2306-L2337), but it's a tad (a very big tad) off the top for me to just leverage it. What you can do is typing the math formulas in Spanish in task items...

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[spanish, french]{babel}
\newcommand\badtrick[1]{\foreignlanguage{spanish}{\ensuremath{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}[item-format=\badtrick](1)
\task 0.6\times0.7=0.42
\task 0.05\times0.1=0.005
\task 0.07\times0.08=0.0056
% added to show the problem with automagically change the decimal mark...
\task a.3\times0.006=0.b
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

(*) I am not so much fond of it (because for example `$a.0$` is rendered as *a,0*; I find cleaner to use `\num{}` from `siunitx` for that task.)